# Error Typescript - Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: typescript

I am facing this issue. I created this simple app.ts to learn about promises in Typescript:

```
import {Promise} from 'es6-promise'

(() => {
console.log('inicio');

const prom1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('Se termino el timeout');
    }, 1000);
});

prom1
    .then(mensaje => console.log(mensaje))
    .catch(err => console.warn(err))

console.log('fin');
})();
```

Then I compile this (tsc app.ts). And it had create an app.js:

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var es6_promise_1 = require("es6-promise");
(function () {
    console.log('inicio');
    var prom1 = new es6_promise_1.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve('Se termino el timeout');
        }, 1000);
    });
    prom1
        .then(function (mensaje) { return console.log(mensaje); })["catch"](function (err) { return console.warn(err); });
    console.log('fin');
})();
```

Also, this is the tsconfig.json

```
{
  "exclude": ["typescript"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

but when I run this in the browser console, it appears the following alert:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at app.js:2
```

I am frustrated and have tried everything that has appeared on the internet and nothing works. I am trying to learn how to use Angular

Comment: *"but when I run this in the console"* Do you mean the browser console?

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't seem to have any relation to Angular. Where are you trying to run this code, and what TypeScript configuration (see `tsconfig.json`) have you compiled it with?

Comment: Hi... Yes, browser console. And my tsconfig.json is the following:{
  "exclude": ["typescript"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}

Comment: you can set `module` option to `es6` to have es6 import instead

Answer (score 1):

> but when I run this in the console

If you mean the browser console, that's as expected. That code isn't compiled for use standalone in a browser, it's compiled to be used by something that understands CommonJS modules. (Browsers don't, without library/bundler support.)

If you just want to compile TypeScript to JavaScript and run the result in a browser directly, tell TypeScript to output ESM (via the [`module`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module) option, setting it to `"ESNext"`).

But for an Angular project, you probably want to use a bundler like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Rollup](https://www.rollupjs.org/) instead.